# Using javascript to add inline css style with height dynamically calculated from container width

Tags: javascript, css

Our WordPress theme uses the main image of the post as a background image on the blog page. To make this work the developers set a fixed height like so:

```
.hentry .entry-thumbnail-wrap {
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 336px;
}
```

On mobile devices the image is cropped, since the height is fixed. As a quick and dirty workaround I set some CSS media queries, but I would prefer a better solution.

I tried javascript and while I can easily get the width of the container, the script won't add the inline style.

To get the width of the container I use:

```
var box = document.getElementsByClassName("entry-thumbnail-wrap")[0];
```

This fetches the actual width of the first DIV with the class "entry-thumbnail-wrap"

Now, I can calculate the height:

```
var height = box.offsetWidth / 2.5 + "px";
```

I can check the result, and it shows the correct value:

```
window.alert(height);
```

Now, I would like to add this to the already existing inline style:

```
box.style.cssText += height + ';';
```

That does not work. For test purposes, I tried a simple rule like so:

```
box.style.cssText += 'color:red;';
```

That does not work either. Nothing is added to the inline style. What am I missing?

Comment: you're missing a opening parenthesis `(`  here: `box.offsetWidth / 2.5 + "px")`

Comment: use `box.style.height = height;` ?

Comment: Okay I have to wonder: What are you trying to accomplish? Because the code provided would cut off the image _on any screen size_, since it uses `background-size: cover`. So do you want it square? If the aspect ratio is _always_ that amount, maybe try a `:before` with a `padding-bottom: calc(100% / 2.5)` to size the box, if it has no contents. When you do that, the box will remain in a fixed aspect ratio.

Comment: The problem is, that the container has a fixed height. So, the aspect ratio will change on mobile device since height is not adjusted dynamically. For example: Orignal dimensions are 800x400px. On a mobile device width shrinks to 400px, but height is fixed at 400px. The ratio changes from 2:1 to 1:1. Usually, there is no need to set a fixed height. But the developers did not embed the image via HTML but as a CSS background image. This is the reason why the container needs a height value.

Comment: @dippas: The closing parenthesis was a mistake. I edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not try to enforce and aspect ratio with a pseudo element (in this case a `:before`). As long as no other content is inside your `.entry-thumbnail-wrap` - because the pseudo element will fill the aspect ratio you want and push everything else out of the way.

```css
.entry-thumbnail-wrap {
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: auto;
}
.entry-thumbnail-wrap:before {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    /* This will give it an aspect ratio of 2/1 */
    padding-bottom: 50%;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry-thumbnail-wrap" style="background-image: url(http://placehold.it/300x300)"></div>
```

This makes it a fixed aspect ratio at any size. You could potentially limit it with a `max-height` or something on your `.entry-thumbnail-wrap` class.

Comment: Excellent, this does the trick. Much better than my original idea. Thank you!